# How to add and delete the Leaflet OpenStreetMap dynamically

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, leaflet-draw, angularjs, leaflet-plugins

I have to place the Leaflet maps to be placed in the bootstrap grids (maps has to place dynamically with the number of elements coming from the backend i.e number of elements = no of Leaflet maps).

**.component.ts**

```js
for (var i = 0; i < this.sensors.length; i++) {
  if (
    this.getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(
      this.sensors[i].latitude,
      this.sensors[i].longitude,
      this.location_latitude,
      this.location_longitude
    ) < 50.0
  ) {
    var latlng = L.latLng(this.sensors[i].latitude, this.sensors[i].longitude);
    this.sensorsarray.push(this.sensors[i]);

    for (var i = 0; i < this.sensorsarray.length; i++) {
      var v = "map" + i + "";
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.id = v;

      document.getElementById("mapper").appendChild(div);
      div.style.height = "380px";

      map[i] = L.map(v).setView(
        [this.sensors[i].latitude, this.sensors[i].longitude],
        11
      );
      L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
        attribution:
          ' <span style="font-size:17px">' + this.sensors[i].name + " </span>",
      }).addTo(map[i]);
      marker = L.marker(latlng, { icon: sensoricon }).addTo(map[i]);
      circlemark[i] = L.circle(latlng, { radius: 5000, weight: 0 }).addTo(
        map[i]
      );
    }
  }
}
```

The above code is to place the default Leaflet map based on the distance (it has to place with entire width)

And the below code is to place the number of sensors locations coming from the backend including current location name

I have created the on change event for the selection of elements (in HTML I have placed the checkboxes based on the location clicking it has to show and hide the map)

```js
dataChanged(selectsensor, i) {
  console.log(selectsensor);
  var existsflag = 0;
  for (var ind = 0; ind < this.sensorsarray.length; ind++) {
    if (this.sensorsarray[ind].name == selectsensor.name) {
      existsflag = ind;
    }
  }

  if (existsflag == 0) {
    this.sensorsarray.push(selectsensor);
    var v = "map" + i + "";
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = v;

    var mapi = 1;
    if (this.sensorsarray.length % 2 == 0) {
      for (i = 0; i < this.sensorsarray.length / 2; i++) {
        var v = "map" + i + "";
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.id = v;

        var v1 = "map" + (i + 1);
        var divmap = document.createElement("div");
        divmap.id = v1;

        var div1 = document.createElement("div");
        div1.className = "row";

        var div2 = document.createElement("div");
        div2.className = "col-6";
        div2.appendChild(div);
        div1.appendChild(div2);

        var div3 = document.createElement("div");
        div3.className = "col-6";
        div3.appendChild(divmap);
        div1.appendChild(div3);

        document.getElementById("mapper").appendChild(div);

        map[mapi] = L.map(v1).setView(
          [this.sensorsarray[i].latitude, this.sensorsarray[i].longitude],
          11
        );
        L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
          attribution:
            ' <span style="font-size:17px">' +
            this.sensorsarray[i].name +
            " </span>",
        }).addTo(map[mapi]);
        var latlng = L.latLng(
          this.sensorsarray[i].latitude,
          this.sensorsarray[i].longitude
        );
        marker = L.marker(latlng, { icon: sensoricon }).addTo(map[i]);
      }
    }

    if (this.sensorsarray.length % 2 == 1) {
      for (i = 0; i < this.sensorsarray.length / 2; i++) {
        var v = "map" + i + "";
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.id = v;
        var v = "map" + (i + 1);
        var divmap2 = document.createElement("div");
        divmap2.id = v;

        var div7 = document.createElement("div");
        div7.className = "row";

        var div8 = document.createElement("div");
        div8.className = "col-6";
        div8.appendChild(div);
        div7.appendChild(div8);

        var div9 = document.createElement("div");
        div9.className = "col-6";
        div9.appendChild(divmap2);

        div7.appendChild(div9);

        var div10 = document.createElement("div");
        div10.className = "row";

        var div11 = document.createElement("div");
        div11.className = "col-12";

        div10.appendChild(div11);

        document.getElementById("mapper").appendChild(div);
        map[i] = L.map(v).setView(
          [this.sensors[i].latitude, this.sensors[i].longitude],
          11
        );
        L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
          attribution:
            ' <span style="font-size:17px">' +
            this.sensors[i].name +
            " </span>",
        }).addTo(map[i]);
        var latlng = L.latLng(
          this.sensors[i].latitude,
          this.sensors[i].longitude
        );
        marker = L.marker(latlng, { icon: sensoricon }).addTo(map[i]);
      }
    }
  } else {
    this.sensorsarray.splice(existsflag, 1);
    map[i].remove();
  }
}
```

From the above code I have created the logic for placing the maps based on the even or odd number of selection (by default it will show the map with entire width(col-12)if we check the two elements it has to place two maps in the one row,if we check 3 maps means it has to place two maps in row one map in second row with full width,if 4 means two maps in first row and two maps in second row and so on..)

**.component.html**

```html
<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="col-6" [ngClass]="{ 'col-12' : sensorsarray.length %2 ==1 }">
    <div id="mapper" style="height: 385px; border: 1px solid gray"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the id mapper will place the number of maps dynamically.

the checkbox selection elements are..

```html
<ul
  class="list-group"
  *ngFor="let sensor of sensors;let i =index"
  (ngModelChange)="dataChanged(sensor,i)"
  style="margin-left: -25px"
>
  <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
    <li class="list-group-item" style="padding: 5px">
      {{sensor.name}}

      <span style="float: right">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          *ngIf="!checked(sensor.name)"
          class="custom-control-input"
          id="customSwitches{{i}}"
          (click)="dataChanged(sensor,i)"
        />

        <input
          type="checkbox"
          *ngIf="checked(sensor.name)"
          checked
          class="custom-control-input"
          id="customSwitches{{i}}"
          (click)="dataChanged(sensor,i)"
        />
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitches{{i}}"> </label>
      </span>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

But by default first map is showing when checking the selection elemnts it is not loading the map. I don't where I made the mistake I am struggling with this problem and I am new to this Leaflet map

Comment: This is a lot of code, and to go through it mentally without possibility to debug/reproduce it is not very productive, to say the least.